# Riemann-Stieltjes Integral and the Step Function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, self-learning

> Let $a < c< b$ and let $\alpha (x)$ be defined as $\alpha (x) =\begin{cases} 0 & a \le x \le c \\ 1 &c<x \le b \end{cases}$. Show that $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$  if and only if $f$ is continuous at $c$ and that the value of the integral is $f(c)$.

I have been looking for results in in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* that could be of use to prove this and found that theorem $6.15$ (p.130)

*If $a<c<b$, f is bounded on [a,b], f is continuous at c and $\alpha(x)=I(x-c)$ then $\int_{a}^{b}fd\alpha=f(c)$*

seem to cover one of the directions (although I could be proved wrong). The other, $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$, continuous to elude me. Help!

Comment: Are you asking for continuity just from the right side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is continuous at $c$ with $\alpha$ as given.  Then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon$ when $|x-c| < \delta$.

Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ with $||P||< \delta$. We have some subinterval of $P$  such that $c \in [x_{j-1},x_j)$.

Note that

$$S(P,f,\alpha) = \sum_{i=1,i\neq j}^{n}f(\xi_i)[\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})]+f(\xi_j)[\alpha(x_j)-\alpha(x_{j-1})]$$

The first sum on the RHS vanishes since  $[\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})] = 0$ if $i \neq j$.

We have $\xi_j,c \in [x_{j-1},x_j]$ and $|\xi_j-c| \leq ||P|| < \delta.$ Hence,

$$|S(P,f,\alpha) -f(c)|= |f(\xi_j)-f(c)| < \epsilon$$

Thus $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ with

$$\int_a^bfd\alpha = f(c).$$

**Here is the proof of the converse**.

Suppose $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ with $\alpha$ as given and

$$\int_a^bfd\alpha = f(c).$$

Then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P_\epsilon$ such that if $P$ is any refinement and $S(P,f,\alpha)$ is any Riemann-Stieltjes sum then

$$|S(P,f,\alpha)- f(c)|< \epsilon.$$

We have some subinterval of $P$ such that $c \in [x_{j-1},x_j)$. Moreover any $\xi \in  [x_{j-1},x_j]$ can be a tag of the Riemann-Stieltjes sum.

Note that

$$S(P,f,\alpha) = \sum_{i=1,i\neq j}^{n}f(\xi_i)[\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})]+f(\xi)[\alpha(x_j)-\alpha(x_{j-1})].$$

The first sum on the RHS vanishes since  $[\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})] = 0$ if $i \neq j$.

Hence,

$$|S(P,f,\alpha) -f(c)|= |f(\xi)-f(c)| < \epsilon$$

Thus, for any $x$ such that $|x-c| < ||P||$ we have $|f(x)-f(c)|< \epsilon$.

Comment: Wait, dont you need to prove that $\int f d\alpha = f(c)$ ?

Comment: This is the converse $\int f d\alpha = f(c)$ imples $f$ is continuous at c.

Comment: @RRL That is absolutely great! Just to clarify, is it right of me to think $\alpha(x_{i})-\alpha(x_{i-1})=0$ vanishes due to the fact that both $x_{i}$ and $x_{i-1}$ lie in an subinterval of $[a,b]$ on which $\alpha$ is constant?

Comment: @reaLdComplex:  Yes that is correct for $i \neq j$

Comment: To prove the first direction, does it suffice to assume that $f$ is continuous at $c$ from the right?