# Compute $\int_{-1}^2 f \, dg$ in terms of Riemann Integrals. Is this correct?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be continuous on $[-1,2].$ for each of the increasing functions $g$ given below, explain why $f$ is Riemann–Stieltjes Integrable and compute$\int_{-1}^2 f\,dg$ in terms of Riemann integrals.

Computation:

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{if }-1 \le x < 0, \\ 0 & \text{if } 0 \le x \le 1, \\ 1 & \text{if } 1 < x \le 2. \end{cases} $$

$f \in \mathbf{R}([a,b],g)$ as $f$ is continuous on $[-1,2],$ by Theorem 6.21.

$$\int_{-1}^2 f \, dg = \int_{-1}^0 f\,dg+ \int_0^1 f\,dg+ \int_1^2 f\,dg.$$

Since $g$ is differentiable on all three intervals $[-1,0],$ $[0,1],$ and $[1,2],$ we note that

$$
\int_{-1}^2 f\,dg= \int_{-1}^0 f(x)g'(x)\,dx +  \int_0^1 f(x)g'(x) \, dx+ \int_1^2 f(x)g'(x) \, dx.$$

Thus, we've

$$\int_{-1}^2 f\,dg = \int_{-1}^0 f(x)g'(x) \, dx+ \int_0^1 f(x)g'(x)\,dx+ \int_1^2 f(x)g'(x)\,dx = 0$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007620/riemann-stieltjes-integral-and-the-step-function

Comment: So the actual answer will be 3f(c), since the jump in each respective integral is just 1?

Comment: What is $c$? And you have two jumps which each will give a contribution.

Comment: Can you include thm 6.21? I am suspicious that you are applying it correctly. The reason your approach breaks down is that at $0$ and at $1$ you should pick up a dirac delta distribution and not just zero derivative. But, I do not know if you have developed that machine for yourself. Suffice to say, the integral should evaluate to $f(1)+f(2)$ if you understand how to apply the link given above.

Comment: Thm 6.21 just states that f is continuous on [a,b] then it is riemann-stieltjes integrable.